# Why is this queue.join call blocking indefinitely?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-multithreading

I'm playing about with a personal project in python3.6 and I've run into the following issue which results in the `my_queue.join()` call blocking indefinitely. Note this isn't my actual code but a minimal example demonstrating the issue.

```py
import threading
import queue

def foo(stop_event, my_queue):
  while not stop_event.is_set():
    try:
      item = my_queue.get(timeout=0.1)
      print(item) #Actual logic goes here
    except queue.Empty:
      pass
  print('DONE')

stop_event = threading.Event()
my_queue = queue.Queue()
thread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(stop_event, my_queue))
thread.start()

my_queue.put(1)
my_queue.put(2)
my_queue.put(3)

print('ALL PUT')

my_queue.join()

print('ALL PROCESSED')

stop_event.set()

print('ALL COMPLETE')
```

I get the following output (it's actually been consistent, but I understand that the output order may differ due to threading):

```
ALL PUT
1
2
3
```

No matter how long I wait I never see `ALL PROCESSED` output to the console, so why is `my_queue.join()` blocking indefinitely when all the items have been processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join):

> The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
>   queue. **The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls
>   task_done() to indicate that the item was retrieved and all work on it
>   is complete**. When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join()
>   unblocks.

You're never calling `q.task_done()` inside your `foo` function. The `foo` function should be something like the example:

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:
            break
        do_work(item)
        q.task_done()
```

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I was missing, it's been a while since I've worked with multi-threaded python and I completely forgot that.